# Why Linked List item insertion is slower than Array item insertion in Javasript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, linked-list

As we all know that linked list item insertion takes O(1) time irrespective of position while that of array is O(n) depending on position for which worst case is O(n), first position and best case is O(1), last position.

I have checked this in VS Code and surprised to find that insertion in linked list turned out to be **3 times slower** that that for array even when placing the item in starting positions. Why is this so?

```
class Linkedlist{
    constructor(){
        this.head = null;
        this.size = 0;
    }
    add(d){
        this.head = new Node(d, this.head);
        ++this.size;
    }
    displace(){
        let d = this.head;
        this.head = d.next;
        --this.size;
        return d.data;
    }
    place(d){
        if(this.head){
            if((this.head).data >= 14)
                this.add(d);
            else{
                let pre = this.head;
                let cur = pre.next;
                while(cur && (cur.data<14)){
                    pre = cur;
                    cur = cur.next;
                }
                pre.next = new Node(d,cur);
                ++this.size;
            }
        }else
            this.add(d);
    }
}

class Node{
    constructor(data, next=null){
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }
}

let A = new Linkedlist();
A.add(29);
A.add(28);
A.add(27);
A.add(26);
A.add(25);
A.add(24);
A.add(23);
A.add(22);
A.add(21);
A.add(20);
A.add(19);
A.add(18);
A.add(17);
A.add(16);
A.add(15);
A.add(14);
A.add(13);
A.add(12);
A.add(11);
A.add(10);
const start = performance.now();
A.place(13.5);
const end = performance.now();
console.log(end-start);
```

So, here I have implemented a linked list using classes concept and added all elements at beginning before starting timer. And the place function is used to interate the list till either it reaches the last node or find the data value to be equal to or greater than 14, there it places 13.5.

```
let A = [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29];
let j;
const start = performance.now();
for(j=0; j<A.length; j++){
    if(A[j]>=14)
        break;
}
A.splice(j,0,13.5);
const end = performance.now();
console.log(end-start);
```

Similarly, I have done this for array.

[Time for Linked List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDBwO.png)

[Time for Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN2sF.png)

Comment: Your array example is not nearly equivalent to your linked list example.  In your array example, you are doing no insertions.  So it is not surprising that inserting into a linked list is slower than no insertions at all!

Comment: @Razumov - isn't an array `splice` an insertion into an array?

Comment: `linked list item insertion takes O(1) time irrespective of position` how do you figure? your `while` loop suggests otherwise

Comment: @JaromandaX, ah yes! I realize the timing is only on that one insertion, the declaration vs many add calls doesn't matter.

Comment: of course, if by "insertion" you meant insert as the head, then, yes, that would be O(1) - but your code is not doing that, since the `this.head.data` is less than 14 (it's 10)

Comment: @JaromandaX I mean in both the cases iteration is done in order to check the index at which the number is less than 14 and insert 13.5 there, so it happens in array as well. But in case of array after insertion, the higher index items increase their index by 1 which is not the case with linked list. And hence, array insertion should take more time. Then, why it's not happening here?

Comment: for a start, the `splice` code is `native code` so much faster than javascript traversal of a linked list - I think you misunderstand how splice works internally, (not that I know of course, just saying your description seems quite naive_

Comment: Oh it means O(n) can be slower than O(1) at times depending on the cases as they give approximate times, now I get it. Btw I wrote everything clearly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As time complexity tells us something about *asymptotic* behaviour, and the JavaScript array `splice` method benefits from a native implementation, you'll need to test this with larger data sets.

Secondly, your tests are testing two actions at the same time: *finding* a location in the data structure, and *inserting* a value at that location. The finding part has the same O(n) time complexity for both data structures, so it would be wise to remove that aspect from the tests, so you can focus on time used for the insertion only. So that means you should test the insertion at the front of the data structure only.

Finally, the tests should be repeated more than a few times to get reliable results.

Here is a test that inserts a thousand values in both structures, and then times how long it takes to repeat the following action a million times:

- insert a fixed value at the front
- remove that same value from the front again

To ease the tests, I have also renamed the methods in the linked list class so they have the same name as for the Array prototype (`shift` and `unshift`).

```js
class LinkedList{
    constructor(...values) {
        this.head = null;
        this.size = 0;
        for (const value of values.reverse()) {
            this.unshift(value);
        }
    }
    // Use the same method names as Array.prototype has
    unshift(d) {
        this.head = new Node(d, this.head);
        ++this.size;
    }
    shift() {
        let d = this.head;
        this.head = d.next;
        --this.size;
        return d.data;
    }
}

class Node{
    constructor(data, next=null) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }
}

function test(obj, numTests) {
    const start = performance.now();
    for (let i = 0; i < numTests; i++) {
        obj.unshift(123);
        obj.shift();
    }
    return Math.round(performance.now() - start);
}

// Set up
const numValues = 1000;
const numTests = 1_000_000;
const arr = [...Array(numValues).keys()];
const lst = new LinkedList(...arr);
// Repeatedly add and remove a value at the front of the data structure
const arrTime = test(arr, numTests);
const lstTime = test(lst, numTests);
// Report
console.log({ arrTime, lstTime });
```

On my PC, the array operations turn out to be slower with this setup.

Comment: Ah now I remember the fact that array is faster for small datasets, not for large ones. Thanks btw

Comment: i think the test isn't relevant precisely since there's no inner loop for inserting

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev, I explained why the *finding* needs to be excluded if we use the asker's premise that *"we all know that linked list item insertion takes O(1) time"*. As this is only true if we already *have* the insertion position, we should exclude the *finding* of that position from the test.

Comment: @trincot thus the question is not very well formulated